# Why does Lindsay in Freaks & Geeks burst out laughing when she hears Daniel's story?

Tags: plot-explanation, freaks-and-geeks

In the 5th episode of the 1998 series *Freaks and Geeks*, named *[Tests and Breasts](https://freaksandgeeks.fandom.com/wiki/Tests_and_Breasts)*, Lindsay Weir helps Daniel Desario to cheat on his Math test.

Eventually, the Math teacher suspects that they have cheated and they are called into the teacher's office for interrogation. There, Daniel becomes emotional and explains everyone in the room, how he was labelled as a dumb student when he was 11 and him never recovering from it as the reason he doesn't do well in academics. Once Daniel finishes speaking, Lindsay bursts out laughing and goes on like a maniac. Others in the room look puzzled about this and with that scene, the episode ends without any explanation. She is always shown as a person who can contain herself in situations like these, so this seems a little out of her character. What is funny about Daniel explaining himself?

My question is, what was the reason for her sudden outburst?

Comment: Because Daniel had said the exact same speech to her earlier in the episode. She realized it was a rehearsed speech that he was using to make himself appear sympathetic to get out of these kinds of problems... and everyone was buying it.

Comment: @PatrickWynne Ahh that makes sense now! Any idea why didn't they continue that storyline? Because Lindsay and Daniel were about get suspended in any case they were proven guilty and because Lindsay practically blew their cover, they should have been in big trouble. The next episodes don't show any of them facing suspensions or Daniel having a fallout with Lindsay.

Comment: @PatrickWynne put that in an answer! Sounds good enough

Comment: @Sandun Regarding why they didn't continue the storyline: 90's TV shows were usually an "episodic" format - each episode is it's own self-contained story and there are seldom (not *never* but *seldom*) any serious consequences that carry over to future episodes.  The assumption here is that if they did indeed end up getting punished for cheating, it was resolved by the start of the next episode.  (Also note that, as these shows aired on a weekly schedule, it was often implied that there was roughly a week between episodes that we don't see because nothing happened. Again, often, not always.

Comment: @PatrickWynne please add your comment as an answer and include Steve-O's explanation too. I will accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Daniel had said the exact same speech to her earlier in the episode. She realized it was a rehearsed speech that he was using to make himself appear sympathetic to get out of these kinds of problems... and everyone was buying it.

Additional explanation from @Steve-O: Regarding why they didn't continue the storyline: 90's TV shows were usually an "episodic" format - each episode is it's own self-contained story and there are seldom (not never but seldom) any serious consequences that carry over to future episodes. The assumption here is that if they did indeed end up getting punished for cheating, it was resolved by the start of the next episode. (Also note that, as these shows aired on a weekly schedule, it was often implied that there was roughly a week between episodes that we don't see because nothing happened. Again, often, not always.